# Programmatically creating SQL db

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

How do I programmatically create an SQL database (and tables.etc)?

I've used SQLite, and pretty easy and straightforward. But the examples I've seen for SQL, everybody avoids creating a db programatically (using: CREATE DATABASE ...).

The following is SQLite code I've used previous to connect to a db, execute queries, and create the table (if it doesn't exist):

```
    //SET UP CONNECTION STRING
    private void SetConnection()
    {
        sqlconnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source= C:\Users\John\Desktop\database1.db; Version=3; Compress=True;");
    }

    //GENERAL 'EXECUTE QUERY' FUNCTION TO EXECUTE CREATECOMMAND QUERIES
    private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sqlconnection.Open();
        sqlcmd = sqlconnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconnection.Close();
    }

    //TABLE CREATED/LOADED WHEN 'ADD ITEM' PAGE LOADS
    private void add_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetConnection();
        sqlconnection.Open();
        sqlcmd = sqlconnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [table1] ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [item] VARCHAR NOT NULL, [quantity] INTEGER NOT NULL)";
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconnection.Close();
    }
```

What I want to know is if its possible to setup a SQL database and use it in a similar way that I've used SQLite. And if so, how?

Comment: Yes you can.  Basically you connect to the SQL Server in a pre-existing database (tempdb or master are typically used), then execute the `CREATE DATABASE` command from there.  Then you should switch your connection's database to your newly created database (may be easier to disconnect and re-connect).  Then just proceed with your other CREATE statements as you already do.  The way that you test for pre-existence is syntactically different though..

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote.  It's a perfectly reasonable question whose correct answer isn't *quite* obvious..

Comment: @RBarryYoung How do I access the pre-existing "master" db? (I'm using VS2010 IDE)

Comment: There's an attribute in the connection string for it.  Depending on your connection string format it may be either `Initial Catalog=` or just `Database=`.

Comment: I've finally got it working. Thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't it be possible? you need to connect to an existing database first (as mentioned in the comments by RBarryYoung)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [name] = 'MyCreatedDatabase'
)
CREATE DATABASE MyCreatedDatabase
```

Read here about create database options:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Comment: That doesn't really apply. You need a data source to connect to, and then setup the connection...so far I only have `sqlconnection = new SQLConnection("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS [inventorydb]");`...but like I said, I need a data source to connect to (hence the `SetConnection()` function in my SQLite code). How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: As RBarryYoung answered you in the comments to your question, that depends on your connection string. take a look at this link:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/